# How can I change all .class files in a jar(or folder) to .java (or .txt) at once?

Tags: java, github, jar, decompiling, .class-file

I have always used [this](http://jd.benow.ca/) to decompile any .class file to readable format. However, now I need to change around 30-40 .class files to readable format to push to my github. How may I change all the .class files to readable (.java or .txt) at once?

Comment: Do you have a license or permission from the original author to decompile and upload their work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. JAR (or ZIP) all the classes you want decompiled together.
2. Launch JD-GUI and open your jar (zip) archive.
3. Use "File" - "Save JAR Sources" menu option. It will decompile everything from your archive and save their sources into another zip file.

You would then need to unzip the ZIP file, and add it to a git repo before push.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse and once I open my jar archive, it still opens as unreadable .class files. Also there's no "Save JAR Sources" in "File".

Comment: I can't speak to the eclipse plugin.  Have you tried using JD-GUI?